# How to read in column vectors from a .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

So I have data being processed in Python that I'm outputting as a .csv file.  I would like R to be able to read the .csv file in such a way that it turns it into a dataframe in which some of the columns are actually vectors.

Is this even possible and how would I format a .csv so that this could happen?  Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? Just use `dat <- read.csv("file.csv")` and then select the column with `dat$column`, and you'll get a vector. The csv is, by definition, a text file with columns separated with commas and the same number of columns for all lines.

Answer (score 13):

First, [vectors](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector) are simply a sequence of data elements. And [data frames](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame) are lists of equal length vectors.

Hence, you can easily reference [each column](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-column-vector) of a data frame as a vector.

```
df <- read.csv('C:\\Path\\To\\DataFile.csv')

v1 <- df[[1]]  # by column number
v2 <- df[["col1"]]  # by column name
v3 <- df$col1  # by column name
```

Comment: But what if the vectors in the columns aren't all the same length between rows?

Comment: When you import a csv file, all columns of data frame will be same length filled with missing values for those rows. Simply remove missings when defining the individual vectors: `v1 <- v1[v1 != ""]`.

Comment: @Zeke consider marking this as answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the csv in r and it will be a dataframe by default:

```
data<-read.csv("nameOfCSVFile.csv", header=T)
```

You can then slice the dataframe by column and obtain that column as a vector using the `$` operator: `data$header1` returns the first column of the dataframe as a vector.

Just make sure that your .csv file is in the order you want
i.e.

```
header1,header2,etc.
     1,2,etc.
     4,5, etc.
     etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a dataframe is a collection of vectors. If you want to have the data in form of a vector, you simple have to use the subsetting functions:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=5))

 df$X1
## [1]  1.05376208  0.05020266  1.79204302 -1.73712344 -1.29208706
 is.vector(df$X1)
## [1] TRUE
```

So by subsetting, here you get a vector of the data frame column `X1`.